# É possível usar dicionários dentro de listas no Python?

Tags: python

Preciso percorrer uma lista que contém dicionários e apresentar as informações desta. Mas testando aqui os atributos `.item()` e `.value()`  não consegui. Vejam:

```
#6.8 - Animais de Estimação:

Pets = [{'Zeus':{'Tipo':'Gato','Dona':'Luciene'},'Jake':{'Tipo':'Dogão',
                    'Dona':'Ide'},'Bob':{'Tipo':'Cachorro','Dono':'Dartinho'}
    }]

for info in Pets.items: #Classe ITEMS só funciona P\ Dic e não Para Listas :/
    print(Pets('Zeus')) ???
```

Answer (score 6):

No seu caso vc teria de percorrer sua lista e depois o dicionario. Visto que um esta dentro do outro. 
De fato o metodo `items()` nao funciona em listas, mas existe mesmo a necessidade de ter uma lista ? porque nao um dicionario dentro de outro ? para isso :

```
Pets = {'Zeus':{'Tipo':'Gato','Dona':'Luciene'},'Jake':{'Tipo':'Dogão',
                'Dona':'Ide'},'Bob':{'Tipo':'Cachorro','Dono':'Dartinho'}
}

for nome, dado in Pets.items():
    print ("\n Nome: ", nome)

    for key in dado:
        print(dado, dado[key])
```

**Saida:**

```
 Nome:  Zeus
{'Dona': 'Luciene', 'Tipo': 'Gato'} Luciene
{'Dona': 'Luciene', 'Tipo': 'Gato'} Gato

 Nome:  Bob
{'Tipo': 'Cachorro', 'Dono': 'Dartinho'} Cachorro
{'Tipo': 'Cachorro', 'Dono': 'Dartinho'} Dartinho

 Nome:  Jake
{'Dona': 'Ide', 'Tipo': 'Dogão'} Ide
{'Dona': 'Ide', 'Tipo': 'Dogão'} Dogão
```

Para mais informações de uma lida na documentação do python sobre [Nested Dictionary](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary)

Comment: A limitação, nesse caso, é não poder ter dois animais de estimação com mesmo nome.

Comment: Legal! Resolveu aqui, eu usei um Dicionario dentro de outro. Muito Obrigado. Como eu faço pra curtir a resposta ??  ^^

Comment: @NamelessMan Não existe "curtir" aqui. Mas vc pode aceitar a resposta, se achar que ela foi útil e resolveu o seu problema - veja como fazê-lo [**lendo o FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052). E [quando tiver mais de 15 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) no site, vai poder também [**votar nos posts**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) que achar útil. Lembrando que aqui os votos não são como as curtidas do facebook ou outras redes sociais, eles [têm um significado diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @hkotsubo bem colocado

Answer (score 6):

A partir da versão 3.6 do Python, você pode utilizar as dataclasses para estruturar esse tipo de dado. Veja um exemplo:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Pet:
    nome: str
    tipo: str
    dono: str

pets = [
    Pet(nome='Zeus', tipo='gato', dono='Luciene'),
    Pet(nome='Jake', tipo='dogão', dono='Ide'),
    Pet(nome='Bob', tipo='cachorro', dono='Dartinho')
]

for pet in pets:
    print(pet.nome)
```

- [O que são dataclasses e quando utilizá-las?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/376306/5878)