# O que são dataclasses e quando utilizá-las?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Na versão 3.7* foi adicionada as chamadas *dataclasses* que foram concebidas a partir da [PEP 557](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/) e consiste em utilizar um decorador, `dataclass`, em classes "normais".

1. O que são essas dataclasses?
2. Quais os benefícios e malefícios de utilizá-las?
3. Quais as principais diferenças entre uma dataclasse e uma classe normal, sem o decorador?
4. O que justifica o seu uso?

---

<sup>(*) Pode ser instalada na versão 3.6 a partir do PIP, em sua versão corrente 0.6, sendo implementada e mantida pelo próprio autor da PEP: https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses.</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de uso de `dataclass` que será referenciado ao longo da explicação:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Item:
    nome: str
    preco_unitario: float
    quantidade: int = 0

    def custo_total(self) -> float:
        return self.preco_unitario * self.quantidade

item = Item('machado', 10.49, 12)
print(repr(item))
# Saida: Item(nome="machado", preco_unitario=10.49, quantidade=12)
print(item.custo_total())
# Saida: 125.88
```

1. Dataclasses podem ser vistas como uma extensão das classes normais do python. O objetivo é reduzir a repetição e o custo de códigos que são comuns na comunidade.

   A ideia é que muitos programas utilizam classes para um simples armazenamento de dados, e tem sempre que implementar um código repetitivo *"boilerplate"* para funcionar.
2. Benefícios e malefícios

   Considere o exemplo acima. Colocando o `@dataclass` antes da classe foram feitas as seguintes operações automáticas:

   - Criação de um `__init__` que recebe os parâmetros e coloca em atributos em `self`.
   - Criação de um `__repr__` muito mais útil para a classe, que retorna o nome da classe e os atributos ao invés do endereço de memória
   - Criação de funções de comparação `__eq__` e `__ne__` que comparam os atributos por igualdade na ordem, permitindo comparar instâncias da classe com os operadores `=` e `!=`;
   - Opcionalmente criar as funções `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__` e `__ge__`, que comparam os atributos na ordem, permitindo a classe ser utilizada com operadores de comparação `>` `>=` `<=` `<` e com funções de ordenação `.sort()` e `sorted()`
   - Opcionalmente *"congela"* a classe, isso é, não permite a alteração dos campos após a inicialização, para simular um objeto imutável.

   Os benefícios então são óbvios pois você não precisará escrever todo esse código. Ele já estará pronto e testado. Os malefícios são para o caso de você usar `dataclass` quando não precisar de todas estas facilidades. Aí eles serão criados, mas só estarão gastando recursos pois não serão usados para nada.
3. Nenhuma. As classes são iguais, com a única diferença de que métodos são acrescentados para você automaticamente pelo decorador, enquanto você teria que definí-los manualmente (ou não) na classe normal.
4. Veja só como ficaria a classe acima, definida pelo `dataclass`:

   ```
   def __init__(self, nome: str, preco_unitario: float, 
           quantidade: int = 0) -> None:
       self.nome = nome
       self.preco_unitario = preco_unitario
       self.quantidade = quantidade

   def __repr__(self):
       return f'Item(nome={self.nome!r}, preco_unitario={self.preco_unitario!r}, quantidade={self.quantidade!r})'

   def __eq__(self, outra):
       if outra.__class__ is self.__class__:
           return (self.nome, self.preco_unitario, self.quantidade) == (outra.nome, outra.preco_unitario, outra.quantidade)
       return NotImplemented

   def __ne__(self, outra):
       if outra.__class__ is self.__class__:
           return (self.nome, self.preco_unitario, self.quantidade) != (outra.nome, outra.preco_unitario, outra.quantidade)
       return NotImplemented

   def __lt__(self, outra):
       if outra.__class__ is self.__class__:
           return (self.nome, self.preco_unitario, self.quantidade) < (outra.nome, outra.preco_unitario, outra.quantidade)
       return NotImplemented

   def __le__(self, outra):
       if outra.__class__ is self.__class__:
           return (self.nome, self.preco_unitario, self.quantidade) <= (outra.nome, outra.preco_unitario, outra.quantidade)
       return NotImplemented

   def __gt__(self, outra):
       if outra.__class__ is self.__class__:
           return (self.nome, self.preco_unitario, self.quantidade) > (outra.nome, outra.preco_unitario, outra.quantidade)
       return NotImplemented

   def __ge__(self, outra):
       if outra.__class__ is self.__class__:
           return (self.nome, self.preco_unitario, self.quantidade) >= (outra.nome, outra.preco_unitario, outra.quantidade)
       return NotImplemented
   ```

   Como pode ver, é muito código economizado por esse decorador, então, está totalmente justificado o seu uso caso você vá definir esses métodos de qualquer forma. Quanto menos código, menos trabalho e menos chance de erros.