# Mostrar um dicionario dentro de uma classe criado por uma função externa

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar um simulador de ficha de RPG, mas estou tendo problemas para exibir propriamente com os rótulos. A criação corre através da função `criaPersonagem()` que cria um objeto em formato de dicionário (ao menos eu tentei criar assim). Depois quando chamo o objeto numa função `print` só aparece os valores e não os rótulos, estou errando no próprio `print` ou dentro da função `criaPersonagem()`?

```
personagens = ["",]

class personagem:
    def __init__(self,name,genre,race,level,power,damage,health,healthRate,insanity,corruption,strength,agility, intellect, will,perception,defense,size,movement):
        self.name = name
        self.genre = genre
        self.race = race
        self.level = level 
        self.power = power
        self.damage = damage
        self.health = health
        self.healthRate = healthRate
        self.insanity = insanity
        self.corruption = corruption
        self.strength = strength
        self.agility = agility
        self.intellect = intellect
        self.will = will
        self.perception = perception
        self.defense = defense
        self.size = size
        self.movement = movement

    def exibePersonagem(self):

        print(self.name,self.genre,self.race,self.level,self.power,self.damage,self.health,self.healthRate,self.insanity,self.corruption,self.strength,self.agility, self.intellect, self.will,self.perception,self.defense,self.size,self.movement)



def criaPersonagem():
    global personagens
    perso = {}
    perso["name"] = input("Qual o nome do personagem?")
    perso["genre"] = input("Qual o genero do personagem?")
    perso["race"] = input("Qual a raça do personagem?")
    perso["level"] = 0
    perso["power"] = 0
    perso["damage"] = 0
    perso["insanity"] = 0
    perso["corruption"] = 0
    if perso["race"] == "humano":
        perso["strength"] = 10
        perso["agility"] = 10
        perso["intellect"] = 10
        perso["will"] = 10

        perso["perception"] = perso["intellect"]
        perso["defense"] = perso["agility"]
        perso["health"] = perso["strength"]
        perso["healthRate"] = perso["health"]/4
        perso["size"] = 1
        perso["movement"] = 10



    values = personagem(perso["name"], perso["genre"], perso["race"], perso["level"],perso["power"],perso["damage"],perso["health"],perso["healthRate"],perso["insanity"],perso["corruption"],perso["strength"],perso["agility"], perso["intellect"], perso["will"],perso["perception"],perso["defense"],perso["size"],perso["movement"])
    personagens.append(values)


criaPersonagem()
print(personagens[1].exibePersonagem())
```

Comment: O que seria os "rótulos" que você cita?

Comment: As chaves dos dicionarios.

Answer (score 2):

A partir da versão 3.6 do Python você pode utilizar as [dataclasses](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/376306/5878) para esse tipo de estrutura de dados.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Character:
    name: str
    genre: str
    race: str
```

A dataclasse irá gerar para você alguns métodos que são comuns nessa estrutura; um deles, e o principal para este problema, é o método `__init__`, que é criado com todos os campos que você definir. Menos trabalho braçal para nós.

Só com a classe supracitada já poderíamos fazer:

```
woss = Character(name='Woss', genre='male', race='god')

print(woss)
```

A saída seria:

```
Character(name='Woss', genre='male', race='god')
```

Que segue o formato nome da classe, seguido com os campos e valores entre parenteses. Você pode personalizar a saída definindo o método `__str__` da sua classe:

```
@dataclass
class Character:
    name: str
    genre: str
    race: str

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            'Dados do personagem:\n'
            f'Nome: {self.name}\n'
            f'Gênero: {self.genre}\n'
            f'Raça: {self.race}\n'
        )
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-395183)</sup>

Neste caso, a saída de `print(woss)` seria:

```
Dados do personagem:
Nome: Woss
Gênero: male
Raça: god
```

E com isso você consegue automatizar várias coisas. Por exemplo, criar uma função que solicita ao usuário todos os dados do personagem e o cria:

```
def create_character():
    print('New character:')

    info = {}

    for attribute, _type in Character.__annotations__.items():
        value = input(f'{attribute}: ')
        info[attribute] = _type(value)

    return Character(**info)
```

Assim, você poderia fazer:

```
>>> print(create_character())

New character:
name: Woss
genre: Male
race: God

Dados do personagem:
Nome: Woss
Gênero: Male
Raça: God
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AptEveryElectricity)</sup>

Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Wow, show de bola!!

Comment: E facilmente você pode implementar todos os métodos de forma que se adaptam à definição da dataclasse, assim, se quiser alterar a estrutura, poderia apenas alterar a definição dos campos - semelhante como foi feito a função `create_character`, que faz a reflexão da classe para verificar quais são os campos e solicita ao usuário.

Comment: Caraca, ficou bem mais prático! Agora vejo como compensa deixar a preguiça de lado e sair da zona de conforto para se atualizar na linguagem. Ainda mais em Python!

Comment: @ÉderGarcia E ainda dá para melhorar bastante esse código.

Comment: @ÉderGarcia Aqui, https://repl.it/@acwoss/ExpertImportantAnimatronics, por exemplo, eu posso definir valores padrões para alguns dos campos da classe e não solicitar ao usuário na hora de criar o personagem. Como comentei, ainda dá para ir longe :D

Comment: Muito massa @AndersonCarlosWoss esta informação foi um "divisor de águas". Grato por compartilhar sua experiência!

Comment: Que legal isso, não conhecia esse modulo, Obrigado por compartilhar isso.

Answer (score 0):

Entendi que o rótulo é a chave do dicionário.

Fiz poucas alterações:

1) Removi a lista `personagens` que "estava sobrando".

2) Substituí o método `exibePersonagem` pela função `exibirPersonagem` que recebe como parâmetro um dicionário `personagem` e imprime suas chaves e valores.

Segue o código:

```
class personagem:

    def __init__(self, name, genre, race, level, power, damage, health, healthRate,
                 insanity, corruption, strength, agility, intellect, will, perception,
                 defense, size, movement):        
        self.name = name
        self.genre = genre
        self.race = race
        self.level = level 
        self.power = power
        self.damage = damage
        self.health = health
        self.healthRate = healthRate
        self.insanity = insanity
        self.corruption = corruption
        self.strength = strength
        self.agility = agility
        self.intellect = intellect
        self.will = will
        self.perception = perception
        self.defense = defense
        self.size = size
        self.movement = movement


def exibirPersonagem(personagem):
    print("\n--- Info ---\n")
    for k in personagem:        
        print(k, personagem.get(k))


def criarPersonagem():    
    perso = {}
    perso["name"] = input("Qual o nome do personagem? ")
    perso["genre"] = input("Qual o genero do personagem? ")
    perso["race"] = input("Qual a raça do personagem? ")
    perso["level"] = 0
    perso["power"] = 0
    perso["damage"] = 0
    perso["insanity"] = 0
    perso["corruption"] = 0

    if perso["race"] == "humano":
        perso["strength"] = 10
        perso["agility"] = 10
        perso["intellect"] = 10
        perso["will"] = 10

        perso["perception"] = perso["intellect"]
        perso["defense"] = perso["agility"]
        perso["health"] = perso["strength"]
        perso["healthRate"] = perso["health"]/4
        perso["size"] = 1
        perso["movement"] = 10

    return perso    


jogador1 = criarPersonagem()

exibirPersonagem(jogador1)
```

Saída:

```
Qual o nome do personagem? Apuleio
Qual o genero do personagem? Ladino
Qual a raça do personagem? humano

--- Info ---

name Apuleio
genre Ladino
race humano
level 0
power 0
damage 0
insanity 0
corruption 0
strength 10
agility 10
intellect 10
will 10
perception 10
defense 10
health 10
healthRate 2.5
size 1
movement 10
```

Comment: E você nem utilizou a classe `personagem` que ele criou?

Comment: Eita, verdade!!

Comment: então a ideia daquele lista sobrando era para armazenar os objetos nela, sem precisar ter que declarar um objeto novo por uma variável que eu coloque o nome.

Comment: Teria que ver qual a regra para definir as habilidades sorteando os valores, senão vai ficar muito chato utilizando 18 inputs. rsrs

Comment: É que nesse caso estou criando com base no RPG Shadow of the Demon Lord, que ao menos esses status são fechados kkkk

Comment: Estou tentando mudar um pouco o código aqui mas não estou tendo sucesso

Comment: Estou criando mesmo para auxiliar numa sessão minha que vou fazer, ai para n ter que ficar declarando novos objetos pelo código quero automatizar com a função pra ficar adicionando automaticamente e depois eu chamo pelo index.

Comment: Vou tentar ajudar respeitando o escopo da pergunta. Seria legal levar este projeto para  o GitHub. O que acha?

Comment: Assim que eu terminar vou postar no git, ta bem no inicio ainda. por enquanto estou com planos de criar funções para ajudar no controle e criação de fichas e no combate.

Comment: Éder obrigado por auxiliar também.

Comment: Legal @pydoni também curto RPG, será uma satisfação contribuir de alguma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Se puderem voltar a ajudar agradeço muito e acho que depois disso já vou entender completamente as lógicas que faltam. Fui voltar a mexer agora de noite no código e baseando no que o @anderson passou fui tentar entender melhor a dataclasses porém não compreendi muito bem a biblioteca em si, mas o que foi utilizado no código em entendi.

Fui então tentar aplicar uma função para modificar atributos com base na raça durante a criação porem não estou conseguindo incrementar e fazer as atribuição de valores corretamente na função updateByRace(), como eu poderia resolver ela?

Tentei experimentar uma  armazenagem desse objeto em uma lista para conseguir chamar ele com mais facilidade depois mas quando tentava fazer em append parece que virava um dicionario comum, perdendo os atributos de um objeto tambem como conseguiria solucionar isso?

amanha ja devo publica no git o projeto, que assim que terminar esses 2 to-do a criação da ficha de outras raças vai ser rápido de terminar.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,fields,MISSING




personagens = [""]

@dataclass
class character:
    name : str
    genre : str
    race : str
    health : int
    recoveryRate : int = 0
    strength : int = 0
    agility : int = 0
    intellect : int = 0
    will : int = 0
    perception : int = 0
    defense : int = 0
    size : int = 0
    movement : int
    level : int = 0
    power : int = 0
    damage : int = 0
    insanity : int = 0
    corruption : int = 0


    def updateByRace(self):
        if self.race == "humano":
            self.strength = 10
            self.agility = 10
            self.intellect = 10
            self.will = 10

            self.perception = self.intellect
            self.defens = self.agility
            self.health = self.strength
            self.recoveryRate = (self.health)/4
            self.size = 1
            self.movement = 10


    def __str__(self):
        return(
            'Ficha do character: \n\n'
            f'Name : {self.name} | '
            f'Genre : {self.genre} | '
            f'Race : {self.race} \n'
            f'Level : {self.level} |'
            f'Power : {self.power} \n'
            f'Damage : {self.damage} |'
            f'Health : {self.health} | '
            f'recoveryRate : {self.recoveryRate} \n'
            f'STR : {self.strength} | '
            f'INT : {self.intellect} | '
            f'AGI : {self.agility} | '
            f'Will : {self.will} \n'
            f'Perception : {self.perception} | '
            f'Defense : {self.defense} | '
            f'Movement : {self.movement} | \n'
            f'Size : {self.size} | '
            f'Insanity : {self.insanity} | '
            f'Corruption : {self.corruption} \n'

    )






def create_character():
    print('New character:')

    info = {}

    for field in fields(character):
        if field.default == MISSING:
            value = input(f'{field.name}: ')
            info[field.name] = field.type(value)

    character.updateByRace()
    return character(**info)

print(create_character())
```