# Input em múltiplos atributos de uma classe em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, input, método

Olá pessoal estou com uma duvida sobre múltiplos atributos de funções ou métodos através da função `input`.

Por exemplo:

```
class Pessoa():
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade
```

A partir desse código como eu atribuo os atributos a funções `inputs`?

Faço de forma individual perguntando um de cada vez ao usuário?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Nesta minha pergunta a resposta do Anderson pode te ajudar e te mostra uma forma diferente e melhor de fazer isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/395183/mostrar-um-dicionario-dentro-de-uma-classe-criado-por-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-externa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer dessa maneira:

```
class Pessoa():
    def __init__(self,nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade


nome = input("Qual é seu nome? ")
idade = input("Qual é sua idade? ")

pessoa = Pessoa(nome,idade)
```

Comment: maravilha! muito obrigado pela ajuda @eudsonduarte !